# My checkboxes are misbehaving

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a series of checkboxes as part of a form being populated with an ng-repeat. I have form validation on other parts of the form. If I select the checkboxes first, I can select and deselect them individually. If I fill out any other field in the form first and then select my checkboxes, they all get selected. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is the snippet for the checkboxes:

```
<div class="form-section">
    <h3>What days of the week do you want to work on this goal?</h3>
    <div>
        <span ng-repeat="day in days" class="inlineblock">
            <input type="checkbox" class="inlineblock" id="{{ day.name }}" name="selectedDays[]" ng-model="task.days" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(day) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(day)"/> 
            <label for="{{ day.name }}"><span></span>{{ day.name }}</label>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably your form validation is connected with these checkboxes right? Can you show your validation code?

Comment: No validation on the checkboxes currently. I did get it to work though. The only thing is I'm not certain why it is working.

Comment: Yes I know there's no validation - but they are part of the form and its possible they are treated differently because of that. Can you provide a fiddle so we can figure this out ? :)